# Registry keys to add to the "Set defaults by app" list in Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, windows-registry

Does anyone know what is needed to be added to the registry to make an app show up with all its supported file types in the Windows 10 Settings > Apps > Default apps > [Set defaults by app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9ySr1.jpg) list?

Comment: Have you managed to do it?

Answer (score 0):

This is usually accomplished by using DISM and an .xml file.

To see how this file looks like, use this command:

```
Dism /Online /Export-DefaultAppAssociations:"C:\DefaultAssociations.xml"
```

To import, use `/Import-DefaultAppAssociations`.

You can find more info at the [official Microsoft website](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/export-or-import-default-application-associations).

Comment: But how to list all extensions that could possibly be opened with a certain installed app? For apps that already present in "Set defaults by app" menu, for each app there is a list of extensions supported by this app. I guess an app should have some kind of a manifest somewhere.

Comment: This could be another question on its own ... I suppose it depends on the applications themselves.